# Which is faster, numpy transpose or flip indices?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, transpose

I have a dynamic programming algorithm (modified Needleman-Wunsch) which requires the same basic calculation twice, but the calculation is done in the orthogonal direction the second time. For instance, from a given cell *(i,j)* in matrix *scoreMatrix*, I want to both calculate a value from values "up" from *(i,j)*, as well as a value from values to the "left" of *(i,j)*. In order to reuse the code I have used a function in which in the first case I send in parameters *i,j,scoreMatrix*, and in the next case I send in *j,i,scoreMatrix.transpose()*. Here is a highly simplified version of that code:

```
def calculateGapCost(i,j,scoreMatrix,gapcost):
  return scoreMatrix[i-1,j] - gapcost

...
gapLeft = calculateGapCost(i,j,scoreMatrix,gapcost)
gapUp = calculateGapCost(j,i,scoreMatrix.transpose(),gapcost)
...
```

I realized that I could alternatively send in a function that would in the one case pass through arguments *(i,j)* when retrieving a value from *scoreMatrix*, and in the other case reverse them to *(j,i)*, rather than transposing the matrix each time.

```
def passThrough(i,j,matrix):
  return matrix[i,j]

def flipIndices(i,j,matrix):
  return matrix[j,i]

def calculateGapCost(i,j,scoreMatrix,gapcost,retrieveValue):
  return retrieveValue(i-1,j,scoreMatrix) - gapcost

...
gapLeft = calculateGapCost(i,j,scoreMatrix,gapcost,passThrough)
gapUp = calculateGapCost(j,i,scoreMatrix,gapcost,flipIndices)
...
```

However if numpy transpose uses some features I'm unaware of to do the transpose in just a few operations, it may be that transpose is in fact faster than my pass-through function idea. Can anyone tell me which would be faster (or if there is a better method I haven't thought of)?

The actual method would call *retrieveValue* 3 times, and involves 2 matrices that would be referenced (and thus transposed if using that approach).

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: transpose simply returns a `view` if possible -- So it's a fast operation -- That said, if you *can* just switch the way you index your array, that's probably the fastest you can do if you're operating one element at a time.

Comment: It would probably take 5 minutes to test this with your actual data using `timeit`, even less if you're using `ipython` and have `%timeit`. Why not try it and see, rather than asking people to guess?

Comment: I guess I didn't need to make those edits. Thanks for the quick response. The documentation makes perfect sense in light of what you said, mgilson, though before I wasn't sure.

Comment: @abanert I'm not truly sure if this is the purpose of the site, but I will say that this answering of the question turned my 5 minutes of research into ten seconds of googling. Answering easy questions turns SO into a searchable encyclopedia that I and others appreciate.

Comment: What implications does this have for cache optimization? If transpose is just another view, would the two approaches be equivalent? Or am I missing something? (The function call in the example would be slower, though)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In NumPy, transpose returns a view with a different shape and [strides](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html). It does not touch the data.

Therefore, you will likely find that the two approaches have identical performance, since in essence they are exactly the same.

However, the only way to be sure is to benchmark both.

Comment: Perfect. I'll stick with transpose since it's clearly a simpler solution. Thanks!